# Land cover shapefile to raster

Tags: raster, qgis-3, vector

I have a cropped shapefile containing land cover data that needs to be converted into raster so I can use it for curve number calculations. I don't know how I will do this. I have QGIS 3.22 and Global Mapper v23.1.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here should always state what you have attempted, and where you are stuck. If you won't put any effort into helping yourself, you might find that others will be equally enthusiastic about helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the tool in Rater -> Conversion -> Rasterize (Vector to raster). You can find documentation [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-vector-to-raster).

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I didn't know what attribute field to use so I tried all. Thanks again